# How to reverse traverse a file in python for finding a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, reverse, file-search

I'm trying to develop an automation script to search a string in a file through a reverse traversing

Suppose consider below file

```
public function anotherfunction(){

}
    public function SampleFunctionAction() {
1       
2   $sql='SELECT * FROM               
3                     SAMPLE_TABLE'
4       ...                           
10  }
```

I will give input as file path, the line number from where the search should start, and the pattern that need to be find in the file. For eg here I will give the line number as **3** and pattern as   **public function**
But when I tried with below code it is performing the searching from the begin of file not from the line number which is specified

```
def traverse():
    lines = []

    with open(r"filepath.php") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if line.startswith('3'):
                lines = []

            lines.append(line)
            if 'public function' in line:
                do_something(lines)
                break


def do_something(lines):
    print("I've got:")
    print(''.join(lines))
```

Hope someone could help me to find what is missing in my implementation for my requirement.

Comment: Do you know how many characters are in the first 2 lines before hand? you could use `file.seek` but that takes in the number of characters to skip

Comment: File search need to go like 3, 2 ,1..(it should be in a reverse order ) whenever it find the pattern just print that line and then break from the loop

Comment: The question is you cannot start from a given line, but you could start after jumping a certain number of characters. For example you jump 100 characters and you start searching ffrom  the 100th character onwards to the end of the file.

Comment: Is this a large file or is it small enough to read the whole thing into memory?

Comment: Is it not possible to point the line number

Comment: @Apollo2020 It is a large file probably contain 1000 lines

Comment: It is not possible to point to a number. But it is possible to state the number of characters. For example if you new that the first 2 lines had 100 characters, then you will start reading from the 101st character. But you cannot point to lines unless you read everything to memory, which is what you are doing.

Comment: My ultimate purpose is like that I need to search for a string in a file 'SAMPLE_TABLE' if I found then I need get the nearest pervious public function line to identify the string  it belongs to that function